# Toronto neighborhoods - most walkable and best food

Tags: walking, toronto

What are the most walkable neighborhoods in Toronto for tourists? What I am actually looking for are residential neighborhoods where people live, that are particularly walkable in terms of functional daily life - getting to the grocery store, public transport, etc. Not needing a car. I will be a tourist, but I am interested in exploring neighborhoods like that.

Comment: What are you looking for? Mostly walkable or mostly touristy? I have to warn you that this kind of question is often off topic on the site but with enough details of what you are looking for we might be able to answer and it still be being on topic.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the tip about staying on topic - I would definitely like it to be useful and relevant to people! What I am actually looking for are residential neighborhoods that people live, that are particularly walkable in terms of functional daily life - getting to the grocery store, public transport, etc. Not needing a car. I will be a tourist, but I am interested in exploring neighborhoods like that. Thank you!

Comment: there are some objective criteria for walkability, e.g. https://www.walkscore.com/CA-ON/Toronto/Bay_Street_Corridor